# How can I write unit test to test a ASP.NET MVC controller with the following code snippet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

All of these views don't even have a title. So I cannot do an

> Assert.AreEqual("Error",Viewbag.Title);

How else can I test an error controller to ensure **atleast** **85%** code is covered

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult BadRequest()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ServerError()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The best I could come up with was

```
public class ErrorControllerTests : BaseTestController
{
    ErrorController ec = new ErrorController();
    [TestMethod()]
    public void IndexTest()
    {
        var actionResult = ec.Index() as ViewResult;

        Assert.AreSame(ec.ViewData, actionResult.ViewData);
        Assert.AreSame(ec.TempData, actionResult.TempData);

        Assert.AreEqual(actionResult.ViewName,"");
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void NotFoundTest()
    {
        var NotFoundTestResult = ec.NotFound() as ViewResult;
        Assert.AreEqual(NotFoundTestResult.ViewName,"");
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void BadRequestTest()
    {
        var badRequestTestResult = ec.BadRequest() as ViewResult;
        Assert.AreEqual(badRequestTestResult.ViewName,"");
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void ServerErrorTest()
    {
        var serverErrorTestResult = ec.ServerError() as ViewResult;
        Assert.AreEqual(serverErrorTestResult.ViewName, "");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can either put a test around the controller and check the view object returned. Or you can use Selenium to automate UI tests.

Comment: are you sure you need 100% code coverage? It looks unnecessary to write unit tests for these methods

Comment: Why are you trying to test the framework and not your code? MS would have tested this before releasing it.

Comment: @Nkosi exactly my question. Now in order to ensure that there has to be some test you gotta have an assert. But when written, the tests are a mere framework test, which is absolutely rudimentary and pointless. *facepalm*

Comment: @DLNarasimhan, Assuming you are referring to MVC5 and not core, check MS's source code for Controller tests https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/test/System.Web.Mvc.Test/Test/ControllerTest.cs#L1081

Comment: @DLNarasimhan check my attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically trying to test the Framework which should have already been done by Microsoft who owns the framework. You should try to avoid testing code you don't own or control.

That said, here is a work around to test the `ErrorController` that tries to mimic framework functionality and work around the limitations when it comes to unit tests.

```
[TestClass]
public class ErrorControllerTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestIndexView() {
        //Arrange
        var expectedViewName = GetViewNameFromExpression<ErrorController>(c => c.Index());
        var controller = ArrangeErrorController(expectedViewName);

        //Act
        var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);

        //Replicating Framework functionality
        MockExecuteResult(controller, result);

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedViewName, result.ViewName);
        CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(controller.ViewData.ToList(), result.ViewData.ToList());
        CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(controller.TempData.ToList(), result.TempData.ToList());
    }

    private static void MockExecuteResult(ErrorController controller, ViewResult result) {
        try {
            result.View = Mock.Of<IView>();
            result.ExecuteResult(controller.ControllerContext);
        } catch { }
    }

    private static ErrorController ArrangeErrorController(string actionName) {
        var controllerName = "error";
        var context = GetControllerContext(actionName, controllerName);
        var controller = new ErrorController() {
            ControllerContext = context
        };
        context.Controller = controller;
        return controller;
    }

    private static ControllerContext GetControllerContext(string actionName, string controllerName) {
        RouteData rd = new RouteData();
        rd.Values["action"] = actionName;
        rd.Values["controller"] = controllerName;

        var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        mockHttpContext.Setup(c => c.Session).Returns((HttpSessionStateBase)null);
        mockHttpContext.Setup(_ => _.Response.Output).Returns(new StringWriter());

        return new ControllerContext(mockHttpContext.Object, rd, new Mock<Controller>().Object);
    }

    private static string GetViewNameFromExpression<TController>(Expression<Action<TController>> action) {
        if (action == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
        }

        var type = typeof(TController);

        bool isController = type != null
               && type.Name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
               && !type.IsAbstract
               && typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(type);

        if (!isController) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid controller.");
        }

        MethodCallExpression body = action.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        if (body == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression must be a method call.");

        if (body.Object != action.Parameters[0])
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Method call must target lambda argument.");

        string actionName = body.Method.Name;
        return actionName;
    }

}
```

Comment: Great attempt @Nkosi . You seem to be using Moq. Would have been nice if you had avoided it. Nevertheless, answers the question.

Comment: @DLNarasimhan that allowed the framework dependencies to be mocked rather easily.

Comment: whats the type of Mock in Mock.Of<IView> in your code?

Comment: @DLNarasimhan it is a mock of a view that would have been rendered by      the view engine using [linq to mocks](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#linq-to-mocks) which is also part of Moq

Comment: I'm starting with UnitTests and I don't understand what is ErrorController. Could you clarify so a begginer like me could understand? - thanks.

Comment: @GabrielEspinoza this answer directly addresses the original question that was asked by the original poster. They had an `ErrorController` that needed testing. It just a normal controller they named. Reread the question and then look at how my answer relates to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can test for example view name:

```
Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.ViewName);
```

But to do that, you need to specify view name in action return:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller 
{
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }

        public ActionResult NotFound()
        {
            return View("NotFound");
        }
        public ActionResult BadRequest()
        {
            return View("BadRequest");
        }

        public ActionResult ServerError()
        {
            return View("ServerError");
        }
    }
```